# unique constraint in yang models

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

if I have the following model

```
devices {
  device {
     key id;
     interfaces {
        interface {
            key id;
            unique name;        
        }
     }
  }
}

which data is valid or invalid according to yang's key and unique    specification ?
1. devices/device=1/interfaces/interface=1; name = a 
2. devices/device=1/interfaces/interface=1; name = b  // key violation 
3. devices/device=1/interfaces/interface=2; name = a  // unique violation
4. devices/device=2/interfaces/interface=1; name = a  // unique violation ?
```

supposing I store the 'interface' objects in a relational table and mark name as unique column, I cannot have both data row 3 and 4. Is that what the spec is meaning ?

or, 
can I interpret the uniqueness or key constraint as , unique resource path ?
If I do so, the following rows of data do not conflict because they are two different resource urls, because they belong to different devices.

```
devices/device=1/interfaces/interface=2; name = a  
devices/device=2/interfaces/interface=2; name = a
```

what is the right interpretation ? globally unique vs unique within the list parent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is probably: `it is unclear` for nested lists.

> The "unique" constraint specifies that the combined values of all the
> leaf instances specified in the argument string, including leafs with
> default values, MUST be unique within all list entry instances in
> which all referenced leafs exist or have default values.

> [RFC7950, Section 7.8.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.8.3).

> The "list" statement is used to define an interior data node in the
> schema tree.  A list node may exist in multiple instances in the data
> tree.  Each such instance is known as a list entry.

> [RFC7950, Section 7.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.8).

The same text appears in [RFC6020](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.8.3) (YANG version 1).

If you interpret it strictly, you have no choice: you have to make all list entries have a unique `name` globally in order to fulfill the constraint. Note that the same would apply to list's key, due to similar wording.

It is unclear whether this was the intention though.

[RFC6110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6110#section-12.16), which deals with YANG based instance validation using existing XML technologies, interprets it as `unique within parent` and it was created by the same WG: it uses the `preceding-sibling::` XPath axis to enforce the constraint, which does not pick up `device/id=2` interface entries inside `device/id=1`, since `device/id=1/interfaces/interface` instances and `device/id=2/interfaces/interface` instances are not siblings in an XML document.

Note that RFCs are not immune to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `unique` is the same as the scope of `key`. That is, in your example, different devices have separate lists of interfaces. In the same way both devices '1' and '2' have an interface '1', devices '1' and '2' can have interfaces with name 'a'.

Note that, unlike `key`, `unique` can reference descendant nodes. If one wanted to make the names unique across devices then one could use `unique` within the device list:

```
list device {
    key 'id';
    unique 'interfaces/interface/name';
    ...
}
```